# Explaining Poorly Chosen Major and Average Grades

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, changing-fields, major

I am a Mechanical Engineering major applying for Ph.D. programs in Physics (in the US) who was always interested in Theoretical Physics but chose Mechanical Engineering due to a poor career choice at the time of the selection of undergrad major. Being interested in only theoretical physics, I didn't care much about perfecting the engineering subjects and this is reflected in my grades. I have very good scores in Physics courses (except for an applied physics course). I am writing my SoP and have gotten advice from a lot of people that I should explain my choice of a different major despite my interest in physics as well as my average grades in engineering subjects. But I am not sure whether plainly telling them that I got viciously lured into engineering by being told "undergraduate physics education in our country is not good and one can easily switch to physics after the undergraduate program if one has done undergraduate studies in engineering" would help. Also, whether plainly telling the truth that I didn't find engineering interesting and thus, my grades are average would help. It might (wrongly) show that I would not study uninteresting things that are required for some research project.

I have a fair amount of content to write about my interest in Physics, for example, I am pursuing a minor in Physics, I have done a good number of interesting research projects, I have attended some schools on theoretical physics, have taken a graduate course in GR, I have well-identified research interests, etc. etc. Is it required (or helpful) to write about why I chose a different major and why my grades are average in the engineering subjects? If yes then what should be the tone and approach?

Comment: Viciously lured? What, did a professor threaten to beat you up?

Comment: @JonCuster Don't you think there is a difference between luring someone and threatening someone? I guess the whole point of luring is that one doesn't have to threaten the subject.

Comment: Well, how does one 'viciously' lure somebody?

Comment: I did not make any such moral equivalencies in my statements. Certainly, should you let such perceptions into your statements of purpose that will likely not put you in a good light. Take heed of the note about blame-shifting indicated in an answer below.

Comment: **"Being interested in only theoretical physics, I didn't care much about perfecting the engineering subjects and this is reflected in my grades"**, **"It might (wrongly) show that I would not study uninteresting things ... "** Isn't that exactly what happened though? If you take this approach, you'll need to offer convincing evidence that you're now willing to put more effort into uninteresting topics. You spend an awful lot of time with research projects studying things outside your field (in CS at least, I dunno about physics).

Comment: @LordFarquaad It is not what exactly happened. The uninteresting things that I didn't learn didn't have any interesting consequences. I did learn many things that I find uninteresting during my projects in physics, e.g. uninteresting computer languages, that had interesting consequences, i.e. some nice physics result. I think I should emphasize this when I say I am willing to learn uninteresting things if they have interesting consequences.

Comment: @Dvij Well you don't always get to choose the consequences of the things you work on either. The way you've presented this is that you'd only work on something if you've deemed it worthwhile (it has an interesting consequence). As someone who's participated in research, I can tell you that at some point you'll work on something "not worthwhile". People selecting students for research know this too, and saying "no, but I think this project is interesting, I'll study it" isn't worth much.

Comment: @LordFarquaad But then what do people want? Do they want me to say I will blindly do whatever I am entitled to do by the organization and forget the very core of scientific spirit--thinking about why you are doing something?

Comment: Just to clarify, as someone who has participated in toy-research, I do have seen the glimpses of the fact that you don't always end up doing something worthwhile. But, I am just saying that learning how a bridge works have no possible interesting consequence for someone who is narrowly interested in knowing how the event horizon of a black hole behaves. I will study something if the motive of the things is in the right place. That's what I want to express.

Comment: @LordFarquaad By ''consequences'' I meant whether the intended consequences are physics consequences or not. I will learn many uninteresting things for the first cause but won't do much for the otherwise case. So, as I mentioned in my previous comment I should have used the word motive instead of consequences for clarity.

Comment: Regarding the use of "viciously lured", I agree that it's inappropriate to use the term by way of explanation, but I *completely* understand the OP's choice of the phrase. I work in data analytics, though my degree is in Chemical Engineering. As an undergrad I wanted to double-major in Computer Science and Statistics, and my advisor (the VP of Student Services) told me that my choice of majors wouldn't make any sense and the two subjects would **never** compliment each other, and further suggested that if I had the ability to get good grades in both of those subjects then I should . . . "

Comment: Finishing user83582's comment: "choose an engineering discipline instead. So I did and I've never used it.

"Vicious" might be a strong word, but certainly "self-serving" is apt, at least in my case. The school just wanted more engineering alumnae, who probably at the time made better money than statisticians."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do think you should explain your mediocre grades in your major in your application.  Give the honest truth that you feel it was a poor choice of major and you lacked interest in the subject.  It's not perfect, but it's better than no explanation.

The more you can portray it as a story of growing and maturing over time, the better.  Focus on the positive: lessons learned, developing more discipline, finding your passion in your physics classes, etc.

I don't think you should say you were "viciously lured" into engineering.  It doesn't really add anything to the story, and also it comes across as blame-shifting.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and response! I get that telling someone that I was viciously lured into something isn't going to do any good and it will rather do a lot of bad, for example, it will question my ability to take an independent decision at its very core. But, I do need to explain why I took a different major if I have always been passionate about theoretical physics --which is the case and I am planning to mention that in my statement.

Comment: You can say that you were advised that you would do better with an engineering degree than with a physics degree given where you were studying. It may have been genuinely well-meant advice, not vicious luring.

Comment: @Dvij fair enough, I think explaining it is fine.  My point is simply to avoid making it sound like blaming others for the decision.

Comment: You don't even need to mention that someone else recommended it (or lured you into it). If you just say that you thought it'd be better for your career, but that you now regret the decision, you get the message across without any hint of blaming others.

Comment: @Anyon That's quite simple and useful. Many thanks for your guidance!